# Passing in a String argument from Wordpress placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently using Wordpress event manager. There is basically a placeholder feature where when using Wordpress in which text from say the "Excerpt" text area will be saved into a placeholder say #_EVENTEXCERPT. The problem I am having is that when I pass this in as a String argument it yields an error because of the line breaks (I'm guessing)

[Link to console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNoyB.png)

```
jQuery("#event-excerpt").append("<p id ='test'>#_EVENTEXCERPT</p>");
```

Is there any way I can get around this?

Update: Link to console after fixing quote mismatch [Updated console link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYkvq.png)

Comment: simply a quote mismatch...can see it right in the syntax highlighter in question

Comment: The problem is that the text from #_EVENTEXCERPT has line breaks and the compiler doesn't recognize that it is a single block, any work arounds?

Comment: where does it come from? If it's server generated...escape it

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
jQuery("#event-excerpt").append("<p id ='test'>#_EVENTEXCERPT</p>");
```

And also you need to replace the line breaks, something like that:

```
var test = "<p id ='test'>#_EVENTEXCERPT</p>";
test = test.replace("<br>", " ");
jQuery("#event-excerpt").append(test );
```

I dont know if this solve the problem for you, because I just replace the line breaks with spaces.

Comment: Can you show me what you have inside this #_EVENTEXCERPT? Seems like a line break problem. Maybe you should replace the line breaks before append.

Comment: "Test present an entire afternoon of free community events from 12–8pm in celebration of International Jazz Day.<br><br><b>Outside on the Plaza:</b><br><br>12:00-4:45 PM - The mobile Boom Box Stage, with a hip-hop dance show and clinic by FutureArtsNow! and performances by the test" is what it's in there. The problem is if I take away the line breaks than I have to find a work around of somehow getting them back in there

Comment: Updated the answer, check it please!